# Time Capsule Questions

Tags: mac, time-capsule

I'm planing to get Time Capsule and want to clarify some questions:

1.Is it possible to use Time Capsule without connecting it to external network (and the Internet) ? I just want to connect to it from my Macbook and use it as storage for Time Machine and other files.

2.Is it possible to store media files on Time Capsule (mp3, avi, mov) ?

3.Is it possible to use Time Capsule as DLNA server ?

4.Is it possible to backup media files (not Time Machine) from Time Capsule using Crash Plan service ?

5.Can I copy files (images, for example) from iPhone, iPad to Time Capsule ?

Comment: These should all be separate questions, not one, big question. The Stack Exchange format for Q&A works best when you ask one question in a post -- then you can get a single, canonical answer for the question.

Comment: This question comes up on search results for Question 1, for which there is a more thorough answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167070/71739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can connect to it through wifi/cable without the Time Capsule connected to the internet.
2. Yes, you can just store anything on it.
3. No, unfortunately not.
4. I am not familiar with this service. However, you can mount the Time Capsule as an external hard drive and thereby use it as any other backup device.
5. Like answer 4: if the iOS program allows you to copy files to an external source (FTP/ssh/etc.) you can connect the Time Capsule to computer in your network and access the time capsule drive through remotely accessing that computer. I don't believe that the Time Capsule drive can be directly approached by iOS.