# Backing up to an Airport Timecapsule over non-Airport WiFi

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I recently upgraded some gear and I am no longer using my Airport as a wireless host. Instead, I now have another device acting as the primary server for DHCP, Router, and WiFi.

The old Airport is connected via Ethernet to the new device (plugged into the LAN port on the Airport). I have turned the Wireless feature off on the Airport, and set it in Bridge mode.

After making these network changes, my Time Machine is no longer able to find the Time Capsule.

My question is, can Time Machine backup over a Wireless network to a *wired* Airport device?

Simplified diagram of how I'm trying to connect: 
[Mac] -- Wireless Network -- [Router] -- [Airport]

Comment: I found some instructions here http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/answers/how-to-add-a-time-capsule-or-airport-extreme-to-an-existing-network-with-br

Comment: @Buscar웃, thanks for the link. I did everything up to the "Then use an Ethernet cable to connect one of your router’s LAN ports to your Time Capsule’s **WAN** port."

I currently have the Airport connected on one of it's LAN ports. I will test this out.

Comment: That should do it, let me know so we make it a answer and close this as done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes, it can do that but needs to be set up first.

[Here are detailed instructions.](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/answers/how-to-add-a-time-capsule-or-airport-extreme-to-an-existing-network-with-br)

In summary:

Connect your Mac to TC via Ethernet to set it up.

Now Disable the wireless functions of the Time Capsule and, Set your Time Capsule to Bridge Mode.--Update the configuration.

Next: use an Ethernet cable to connect one of your router’s LAN ports to your Time Capsule’s **WAN** port.

Comment: One additional thing: It appears that the network advertisements the Time Capsule sends out only traverse the subnet the device is on. [See Apple Discussion here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1749362?start=0&tstart=0). From that thread, I also had to use Command + K to connect to a server, and then use `afp://<time capsule ip address>`. Once the drive was mounted, I was able to see my old drive in Time Capsule settings.